# Openjpa cascade persist sets foreign key to null

Tags: jpa, null, foreign-keys, cascade, persist

I have 2 entities: *Routes* and *Hosts*. *Hosts* has a FK-field route_id referencing to *Routes'* PK also called route_id.
I create object *Routes* and add *Hosts* objects to it's hostsCollection. Then I persist *Routes* object. Both primary keys are generated correctly, new *Routes* record is ok, but *Hosts* record has NULL in route_id field. What am I doing wrong?

Routes.java:

```
@Entity
public class Routes implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ROUTE_ID")
    private long routeId;

    @Column(name="MSG_QUEUE_NAME")
    private String msgQueueName;

    @Column(name="RECEIPT_QUEUE_NAME")
    private String receiptQueueName;

    @Column(name="QM_NAME")
    private String qmName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="routeId", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private Set<Hosts> hostsCollection;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Routes(String mqMgrName, String msgQName, String receiptQName, Set<Hosts> newHosts)
    {
        this.qmName = mqMgrName;
        this.msgQueueName = msgQName;
        this.receiptQueueName = receiptQName;
        this.hostsCollection = newHosts;
    }
    ...
}
```

Hosts.java:

```
@Entity
public class Hosts implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="HOST_ID")
    private long hostId;

    @Column(name="HOST_NAME")
    private String hostName;

    @Column(name="KEEP_MSG")
    private String keepMsg;

    @Column(name="SEND_RCPT")
    private String sendRcpt;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="ROUTE_ID", referencedColumnName="ROUTE_ID")
    private Routes routeId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="hostId")
    private Set<Users> usersCollection;

    public Hosts(String hostName, String keepMsg, String sendRcpt)
    {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.keepMsg = keepMsg;
        this.sendRcpt = sendRcpt;
    }
    ...
}
```

Creating objects:

```
public String createNewHost()
{
    Set<Hosts> newHosts = new HashSet<Hosts>();
    Hosts newHost = new Hosts(this.hostName, this.keepMsg, this.sendRcpt);
    newHosts.add(newHost);
    Routes newRoute = new Routes(this.mqMgrName, this.msgQName, this.receiptQName, newHosts);
    dataBean.setCurrentRoute(newRoute);
    return "ok";
}
```

Persisting objects:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void setCurrentRoute(Routes currentRoute) {
    em.persist(currentRoute);
    em.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Routes.hosts you have mappedBy="routeId" which means, that owning side of relation is Host.

So unless you set relation on Host, it will not be persisted.